# data content for listview isn't change from option menu?

Tags: android, listview, menu

In my code i'm fetching inbox messages to my application in `listview` what i want is i'm providing `show view` as a `option menu` item which changes the data `listview` will show i.e (1) first view is `All inbox messages will be displayed` (2) `only messages from unknown no's will be displayed` But when i'm running my application nothing is displaying in listview. 
Can any one tell me how to do this....

```
public void getInboxSms() {
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    c = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);
    totalSMS = c.getCount();
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < totalSMS; i++) {

            Log.d("SMSss", "Contact number : "+ c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address"))+ "\n"
                            + "msg : " + c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")
                            + "\n"
                            + "Person : "
                            + getContactName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address"))));
            c.moveToNext();
        }
    }
}

public String getContactName(String phoneNumber) {
    ContentResolver cr = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
            Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
     Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri,
            new String[] { PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME }, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        return null;
    }
    String contactName = null;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        contactName = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
    }
    if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
    }
    return contactName;
}

private List<SMSListModel> getModel() 
{
if(c.getCount()>0)
{
    for(int i=0;i<c.getCount();i++)
    {
        if(c.moveToPosition(i))
        {
            if(getContactName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address"))) == null ){

                list.add(new SMSListModel(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address")),c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("body"))));
            }   
            }
    }
}
return list;        
}
```

Code in option menu:

```
case R.id.action_showview:
            AlertDialog.Builder sDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            sDialog.setTitle("Select Message Type");
            sDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_sort_by_size);

            sDialog.setSingleChoiceItems(Select_view,-1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int sitem) {
                    selectposition = sitem;
                    // get selected value
                     String Select_value = Select_view[sitem].toString();
                     if(Select_value.equals("All Messages")){

                         list.add(new SMSListModel(getContactName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address"))),c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("body"))));

                     }
                     else if (Select_value.equals("Unkown Number")){
                         if(getContactName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address"))) == null ){

                                list.add(new SMSListModel(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address")),c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("body"))));

                            }
                     }
                     else {
                         if(getContactName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address"))) == null ){

                                list.add(new SMSListModel(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address")),c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("body"))));
                                //listFormat.add(new SMSListModel(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address")),c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("body"))));
                            }
                     }

                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert_dialog = sDialog.create();
            alert_dialog.show();

            // set default select value
            alert_dialog.getListView().setItemChecked(selectposition, true);
```

Comment: Did you use the debug option?

Comment: @Nun'e Chai i don't know how to implements this...

Comment: The best thing to do would be to learn debugging, you can find a plenty of examples online. [This](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html) would get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that Select_view array have values at the time of creating Dialog?

Comment: actually i don't know how to implement that thing that's why i've put my code regarding this.... thanks

Comment: where you are assigning the value in Select_view variable?

Comment: The place where you are passing Select_view variable takes an String array as an argument. So you have to make sure that the variable Select_view should have the values before assigning them to the dialog. e.g:- instead of Select_view variable you just pass "new String[]{"One", "Two", "Three"}" and see you will get the rows in List View.